# have any one used plutoSDR via python

Tags: signal-processing, iio, rtl-sdr

I'm trying to detect UAVs using RF signal.. so I just bought ADALM-PLUTO SDR.

I think I need to use adi library to use this on python, but the thing that makes me confused is sdr.rx() method.

this method returns the complex value like -3+24j, but I haven't seen  IQ value like this.
I don't understand why each I and Q value is too big and integer.

I'd like to ask if there's  someone who knows how sdr.rx() works..